# Why を and not に in 今日は先輩に2回**を**注意されました。?

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

今日は先輩に2回**を**注意されました。
[today][by senpai][2 times were adviced/warned]??? does this make any sense?

Shouldn't it be rather:
今日は先輩に2回**に**注意されました。
[today][by senpai][2 times （I/He/She..etc) were adviced/warned]??

Comment: Can you provide the source of this sentence and some context?

Comment: @kandyman unfortunately i don't have neither. It's a random sentence i'm i'm training with.

Comment: Maaybe you misread 「今日は先輩に**2回注意を**されました」, no?

Answer (score 4):

> 今日は先輩に２回**を**注意されました。
> 今日は先輩に２回**に**注意されました。

Both sound incorrect, I'm afraid. You'd say:

> 今日は先輩に**２回**注意されました。

２回 ("twice") functions adverbially.

---

<sub>"Numeral+counter" often functions adverbially. eg:</sub>

<sub>鉛筆が**２本**あります。

リンゴを**２つ**食べました。</sub>

Comment: This sentence: '姉に部屋の掃除**を**頼まれました。'  also doesn't look comfortable to me.
is を put in the wrong place here too?

Comment: 姉に部屋の掃除を頼まれました is perfectly correct. 部屋の掃除 is the direct object of the verb 頼む, so it's marked with を.